# How find MapView an Overlay ist put onto?

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I do have an Overlay that's used on several kinds of MapViews. Now I need to invalidate the MapView from within the Overlay in one single situation.

I couldn't find a way to get the MapView this Overlay is drawn on. Is there a way to find the MapView from within the Overlay?

Yes, I know, I can put the MapView in an additional constructor of the Overlay, but first I want to try if this is possible without an additional constructor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either try putting the Overlay inside the MapView to make it an inner class, but in that case you probably wouldn't be able to use it elsewhere, OR try good old pattern observer perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

the MapView is passed to most methods - really depends when you have to invalidate:

```
public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas,
        MapView mapView,  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        boolean shadow)
```

also passed to onKeyDown, onKeyUp, OnTap, OnTouchEven, onTrackballEvent

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was my first thought too. But I can't be sure that one of these events come in before I need to invalidate.